# Логин только с одного клиента одновременно django

Tags: python, django

Есть ли возможность сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог залогиниться только с одного устройства и при входе на другом предыдущая сессия заканчивалась бы? К примеру пользователь входит в свой аккаунт на сайте через браузер с компьютера, потом через некоторое время он заходит в свой аккаунт с, к примеру, планшета и в этот момент он автоматически выходит из браузера на компьютере. Буду рад услышать ваши рекомендации по поводу реализации.

Comment: возможность есть

Comment: Запоминайте где-нибудь текущую сессию (например в модели User), а в момент появления новой сессии стирайте запомненную старую сессию

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы разлогинить пользователя нужно вызвать функцию from django.contrib.auth.logout
Вот код этой функции

````py
def logout(request):
    """
    Remove the authenticated user's ID from the request and flush their session
    data.
    """
    # Dispatch the signal before the user is logged out so the receivers have a
    # chance to find out *who* logged out.
    user = getattr(request, 'user', None)
    if not getattr(user, 'is_authenticated', True):
        user = None
    user_logged_out.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
    request.session.flush()
    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
        request.user = AnonymousUser()

А это код django.contrib.auth.flush
```python
    def flush(self):
        """
        Remove the current session data from the database and regenerate the
        key.
        """
        self.clear()
        self.delete()
        self._session_key = None
````

И еще для полной картины нужно посмотреть django.contrib.auth.login, но она слишком длинная, но суть в том, что после успешной аутентификации, создается сессия и записывается в хранилище(memcached, redis, DB, файл, куки)

Проблемма в том, что мы не знаем объект request компьютера заходя с мобильного.
Но при аутентификации мы можем сохранить в свою модель юзер SESSION_KEY, предварительно расширив модель User конечно. Далее все сводится к тому, что мы берем наш SESSION_KEY (см. функцию login) и удаляем сессию из нашего хранилища, тем самым разлогинивая старого пользователя.
Но есть одно но, что может быть некоторый глюк(это нужно проверить) когда вы удалите сессию, а она снова сохраниться. Это может произойти при одновременной работе с одного логина на разных устройствах.
Например, вы заходите с компьютера, уже залогинились, и выполняете какой то длинный http запрос длинной в 1 мин. В конце работы запроса вы добавляете параметр в сессию и сохраняете ее, хотя вы 30 сек назад залогинились в телефона и удалили сессию компьюетар по SESSION_KEY.

Это можно протестировать, создав вьюху и сделав в ней time.sleep(60) симитировав работу долгой вьюхи. Если такое произойдет, то можно переписать SessionMiddleware и поставить вместо стандартной свою middleware, в которой вы будете проверять SESSION_KEY, и если он изменился(вы залогинились с телефона), вызывать logout()

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved